# How to upgrade from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2012 R2 (Standard Edition)?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I've been trying to understand how to upgrade from from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2012 R2 (Standard Edition) and I can't find the installer/upgrade to download anywhere.

Does someone know where to get the upgrade?

Thanks!

Comment: 2012 R2 is not just a free upgrade from 2012.  You need a 2012 R2 license and the full install media.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dn527667

Comment: @Martin could you please valide my answer if it did help ?

Answer (score 3):

To upgrade from Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2012 R2, you can use the installation media of Windows Server 2012 R2. During the setup process, you will be prompted to choose whether you want to perform a clean install or an Upgrade.

If you have a valid license but no installation media, you should be able to download it via the official site. Choose to try the product, you will be redirected to the download page.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2012-r2/default.aspx

Here is an additional post that will interest you. It contains a link to the TechNet article about the upgrade path.

[Microsoft License Windows 2012 R2](https://superuser.com/questions/745435/microsoft-license-windows-2012-r2/747411#747411)

Hope this helps.