# Microsoft License Windows 2012 R2

Tags: license, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Can I update Windows server 2012 standard to Windows server 2012 standardR2 without a license update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard and R2 require two different keys, so if you want to upgrade to R2 you will have to get a new key.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2 are two distinct products.

Thus, each require a separate product key to be activated.

If you have a valid product key for Windows Server 2012 R2, you should be able to upgrade your server.

Here are more informations regarding upgrade path for Windows Server 2012 R2 :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303416.aspx

Hope this helps !